# What does "what is at" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

One of my friend asked me if İ know what  "what is at" could mean. l would like to know what this phrase means.

Comment: Can you please show the example usage, in a complete sentence? A link to a source would be good, if you have it.

Comment: Indeed. This is unanswerable without context.

Comment: In fast speech, in the phrase "What's that?" the first consonant in *that* sometimes becomes an /s/. This results in the following pronunciation /wɒts sæt/, which is easy to hear as "What's at?"